# How to increase space between values on x-axis of box plot?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have the below code for a boxplot and as you can see all values along x-axis are not spaced. How can i adjust this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_excel("RBA_KYC_Accounts_ALL_Ids.xlsx")

sns.boxplot(x='profession', y='rbaValue', data=df, width=0.8, palette="PRGn")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your 'profession' seems to be in floating point format. You can change it to integer format via `.astype(int)`.  With `plt.subplots` you can also set a wider `figsize`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'profession': np.random.randint(1, 31, 200) * 1.0,
                   'rbaValue': np.random.binomial(100, 0.02, 200)})
df['profession'] = df['profession'].astype(int)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
sns.boxplot(x='profession', y='rbaValue', data=df, width=0.8, palette="PRGn", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]